# C++ classes - how return vector of custom type from a function?

Tags: c++, class, vector, declaration

I am having trouble setting up my functions in a class when I want to have a function return a vector of type `struct` which I have just defined. Compiler gives a "Use of undeclared identifier" error.

In the .h file: (no errors given)

```
struct workingPoint;

public:

vector<workingPoint>calculateWorkingPointCloud();
```

And in the .cpp file:

```
struct DeltaKinematics::workingPoint {
    int x, y, z;
    //more stuff to come
};

vector<workingPoint> DeltaKinematics::calculateWorkingPointCloud(){ //error here is "Use of undeclared identifier 'workingPoint'

}
```

It seems that the compiler doesn't know what a `workingPoint` is, despite the fact it is declared before the function?

Comment: Both @DeadMG and @mkaes solved my issue. After reading @mkaes question's answer I have also moved my declaration of the struct into the header, which seems like best practice. Hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simply a problem of the lookup. You need to fully qualify the name, e.g.
`vector<DeltaKinematics::workingPoint> DeltaKinematics::calculateWorkingPointCloud(){...`

I asked a similar question about this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662723/typename-lookup-of-return-parameter). Maybe it is also interesting for you.

Comment: Thanks that works :), that was a nice full answer you got for your question, very informative.

Answer (score 3):

You defined a structure `DeltaKinematics::workingPoint`, and then tried to return a structure `workingPoint`. You need the explicit qualification.